# Slow loading of js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, jquery-easyui

I use jeasyui and I call the js files using requirejs but I am having problems, when I load the website. Applications such as late picking js file, which resulted in the website displays a white screen and the screen is cluttered..

How to config requirejs correct and fast?

myconfig

```
//load js file very lazy
 define(["jquery", "jquery.easyui","jquery.alpha", "jquery.beta", 
"jquery-ui"], function($) {
   $(function() {
    $('body').alpha().beta();

   });
 });
```

[image: js file]

[image: slow load js]

Answer (score -1):

I think the code is fine. Maybe because of your slow network. In Chrome, you can right click on the webpage and click "Inspect element". Then choose "Network" to see which JS file takes most time to load. Just like:

[image]

Or you should put all JS loading statement at the bottom of the HTML file. In this case, the webpage elements are loaded and displayed first.